# Union of a locally finite collection of compact set is compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I want to know the union of a locally finite collection of compact set is compact.

First I know the following facts(theorems);

0. finite set is compact and finite implies locally finite.
1. Union of a finite collection of a compact set is compact.
2. Every locally finite collection of subsets of a compact set is finite (hence locally finite)

---

So the finite union of a locally finite collection of compact set is compact, but how about the general case? I mean countable union of a locally finite collection of compact set is compact?

Comment: Is $\bigcup [2n,2n+1]$ compact?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. Let $K_n = \{n\} \subset \mathbb R$. The $K_n$ form a locally finite family of compact subsets of $\mathbb R$, but their union is not compact.